# Continous Integration Server in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, hudson, cruisecontrol.net

I would like use a continuous integration system in my projects. However, I don't want to use a server sitting in my office, instead I'd like my continuous integration server to run on Windows Azure.  Has anyone set this up? Are there recipes to host Hudson or CruiseControl.Net (or any other CI system) within Azure?

Comment: If the CI server runs in Azure, how would it talk to your source control server?

Comment: It would be possible to use Azure Connect (currently in beta)

Comment: In my case, the source server is internet facing.

Comment: My students have precisely started to design a cloud integration server for Windows Azure, see http://code.google.com/p/cassis/ However the problem is still in very early stage.

Answer (score 0):

We use the Build Manager in Team Foundation Server to push our automated builds to Azure. We set up our Azure hosted services to allow for Web Publish through remote desktop using this plugin - http://dunnry.com/blog/2010/12/20/UsingWebDeployWithWindowsAzure.aspx

You do not need to involve Team Foundation Server to use the plugin - you can set up your instances to publish to azure instantaneously through Visual Studio Web Publish without CI.

I think there are two parts to the Azure CI solution - automated builds from your source control and actually pushing the bits to azure. The plugin makes the publish to Azure much, much faster. So if you want real time access to changes on Azure, you will need to look into the plugin.

Comment: I want the CI to run within Azure. I could use this system for software projects that have nothing to do with Azure. In this question, I want to use Azure as a scalable host for my CI solution.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use Azure as an infrastructure provider, which runs a VM where your builds happen.

This is not a particularly good use-case for Azure.  Azure is a platform to run your custom-built applications.  While it does provide VM's similarly to Amazon or other IaaS cloud providers, those VM's are "stateless", can go up and down at will and meant to act as application servers where more than one can be up at any given time.

You can probably get this to work on an Azure VM but I am not sure if the pain would be worth it.

Azure's instances are application servers, not "windows servers".

HTH

Comment: Your point about Azure not being IaaS is well taken, but isn't CI a good application for PaaS? For example, aren't build slaves - http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Distributed+builds a great use case for PaaS?

Comment: I think slaves running on Azure should work... I'm struggling with seeing how the master would run.

Comment: (This is a great conversation, and I think you are bringing up excellent points) As I understand it, a master is just a front end, which reads persisted state, and requests jobs to be executed.  This could be Web Role for front end +  Blob/Table for storage;  For availability I expect you'd need 2 web roles.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Jenkins on Windows Azure, it works very well for me.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gongcheng/archive/2013/02/27/jenkins-on-windows-azure-the-missing-manual.aspx