# How should I configure Jenkins CI (or Hudson) to run on Azure?

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I like Jenkins, and it strikes me that being able to spin-up extra build slaves on-demand in Azure could work well.

Besides, the less on-premise hardware I have to maintain, the better.

Has anyone configured Jenkins (or, indeed, Hudson) to run in Azure? Technically I suspect it shouldn't be too tricky - I'd appreciate pointers to resources that might help. The tricky bit is likely to be persistence of the build state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done that, it seems to be working fine for me. There is a little bit nuances, but generally works.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gongcheng/archive/2013/02/27/jenkins-on-windows-azure-the-missing-manual.aspx

Step by step for Master:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gongcheng/archive/2013/04/16/jenkins-on-windows-azure-the-missing-manual-master.aspx

Step by step for Slave:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gongcheng/archive/2013/04/16/jenkins-on-windows-azure-the-missing-manual-slave.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Now that we have VM roles (which we didn't when I posted the question) this is much easier than it used to be.

Answer (score 0):

Check out: [Continous Integration Server in Windows Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572825/continous-integration-server-in-windows-azure)