# Utilizing EC2 or Azure to scale out a distributed C# build system?

Tags: build, azure, continuous-integration, amazon-ec2

Quite a few build and CI systems support steps for pushing build output to Azure, but I haven't seen any which can actually run **on** Azure (or EC2). Ideally I would like to be able to spin up an arbitrary number of instances (depending on the # of pending submits) to deal with the actual build + quality gates (UTs, FXCop, other static analysis tools) + source repository checkin process.

Are there existing tools which can do this, or has anyone built something which they can discuss?

Thanks!

[Edit: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572825/continous-integration-server-in-windows-azure) which is quite similar but didn't have any informative answers, so I'll keep my question alive]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open souce [Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/) CI server has an [EC2 plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Amazon+EC2+Plugin) that will spin up EC2 instances automatically depending on your build load.  I couldn't find anything for Azure, but I highly recommend Jenkins - it's easy to configure, well maintained and has stacks of features.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Git or Mercurial for source control, AppHarbor might be what you're looking for.  It's a CI build/deploy environment that runs exclusively in the cloud (EC2), and can deploy build output to Azure.

Here are some links for reference:

http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/appharbor-heroku-for-net/987

http://lostechies.com/chrismissal/2011/03/12/using-appharbor-for-continuous-integration

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/12/making-let-me-bing-that-for-you-open-source.aspx

http://appharbor.com/page/pricing

Comment: "but deploys build output to Azure" - I think you may be mistaken. As far as I know it does everything in EC2. They market themselves as "Azure done right" - inasmuch as it's .NET cloud hosting, they don't run on Azure.

Comment: Provided the CSPack executable (and its dependencies) are included in source control, one could upload a package to azure by executing CSPack with the appropriate parameters.  I'll reword my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Continuous Integration on Windows Azure http://code.google.com/p/cassis/ (over Mercurial)

*Disclaimer: work produced by my 1st year CS students*

Answer (score 1):

Also Teamcity has support for this: http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/features/amazon_ec2.html